# formula field for display text datatype to number data type?

Tags: formula-field

i have one text field having number its displaying value like this '1000' but i need to display like this '1,000' for this i created formula field if i took return type number means it will achive but we can't do like that error coming inavalid return type. how can i achive this?

i used this code

```
TRIM(
  IF(LEN(userid__c)>15, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,18,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)>12, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,15,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 9, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,12,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 6, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 9,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 3, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 6,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 0, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 3,' '), 3)      ,'')
)
```

but its not getting proper output if i gave '12345' means it returns '12,123'. please help on this

Comment: Write a formula `VALUE(field__c)`. This will convert text data stored in `field__c` into a number.

Comment: Not sure there is a formula to take numbers like 12345 and turn them into 12,123 unless there is a set conversion factor. For straight text to number Rohit has the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160451/how-to-convert-text-field-number-value-to-text-in-formula-field

Comment: I answered [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/160554/12440). This has to be flagged as duplicate